# Interconnecting IDs that are linked

Tags: mysql

I have a `linked_persons` MySQL table that contains 2 columns: ID, and LID. Both columns refer to PersonID (from a different table). The idea behind this `linked_persons` was to show relations between 2 persons.

This `linked_persons` table was setup by someone else, and I can't modify it. But, here is what I've learned about this table:

- Every ID is linked to itself.
- The idea was to use ID as the identifier for the "primary" / "main" person in the family. And, every linked child/sibling would be listed as the LID. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. In some cases ID refers to the "primary" person, and in other cases, LID refers to the "primary" person.

I've built an SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb6bf4 that has some sample data on how the entries are made.

I am trying to build a view on top of this `linked_persons` table that will "interconnect" all linked persons. i.e. I need to be able to get IDs of all the members of this linked_persons if I search for any member in the "family". I need to be able to search for the member's ID in either ID column, or LID column.

So, based on the SQL Fiddle, I'm trying to generate the following result:

```
ID | LID
--------
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
1  | 4
1  | 5
2  | 1
2  | 2
2  | 3
2  | 4
2  | 5
3  | 1
3  | 2
3  | 3
3  | 4
3  | 5
4  | 1
4  | 2
4  | 3
4  | 4
4  | 5
5  | 1
5  | 2
5  | 3
5  | 4
5  | 5
6  | 6
```

My first idea was to use a query like the following, which doesn't work because IDs 4 and 3 aren't linked to each other (directly).

```
SELECT ID, LID FROM linked_persons
UNION
SELECT LID AS ID, ID AS LID FROM linked_persons
```

Comment: not sure, what exactly you are looking for

Comment: I'm essentially looking for a query that will generate the above result based on the data that's in the SQL Fiddle. :)

Comment: this is very simple or I understood wrong.

Comment: It very well might be, but I feel like I keep over-complicating it, and end up with the wrong result. Can you share your solution?